# Outlook 2007 image alignment issue

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have a table defined as

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
 <td width="600">
  <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="25">
 <tr>
  <td width="210">Content 1 with grey background</td>
  <td width="390">COntent 2 with white background</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="600" colspan="2"><img src="image.jpg" width="600"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now this image.jpg has 210 px as grey background and 390px as white background in order to align with the above table cells.

However, it shows up as non aligned in outlook 2007. It shows up fine in others.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're lucky it shows at all. The `background` property is loosely if at all supported by most email clients. I would suggest against using it or using just an `<img>` tag instead.

Here's more info on what outlook 2007 supports:

http://www.email-standards.org/clients/microsoft-outlook-2007/

Comment: Yes, in general DO NOT use background images in HTML email.